# How do I use flask.url_for() with flask-restful?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have setup Flask restful like this:

```
api = Api(app, decorators=[csrf_protect.exempt])
api.add_resource(FTRecordsAPI,
                 '/api/v1.0/ftrecords/<string:ios_sync_timestamp>',
                 endpoint="api.ftrecord")
```

I would like to redirect internally to the endpoint `api.ftrecord`.

But the moment I try to do this:

```
base_url = flask.url_for('api.ftrecord')
```

I get an exception.

```
  File "/Users/hooman/workspace/F11A/src/lib/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1620, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('api.ftrecord', {}, None)
```

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 20):

You'll need to specify a value for the `ios_sync_timestamp` part of your URL:

```
flask.url_for('api.ftrecord', ios_sync_timestamp='some value')
```

or you could use [`Api.url_for()`](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Api.url_for), which takes a resource:

```
api.url_for(FTRecordsAPI, ios_sync_timestamp='some value')
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising. I should have mentioned I am trying to achieve this from the unit test perspective. `self.client = application.app.test_client()`. I get the error `RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.`

Comment: See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/; for any test you'll need to create a context.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem today. Here's the pull request that added the functionality (11 months ago):

https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/pull/110

You can see his example usage there.

In my resources file, I do not have access to the app context. So I had to do this:

```py
from flask.ext import restful
from flask import current_app

api = restful.Api
print api.url_for(api(current_app), UserResource, user_id=user.id, _external=True)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
api = Api(app, decorators=[csrf_protect.exempt])
api.add_resource(FTRecordsAPI,
                 '/api/v1.0/ftrecords/<string:ios_sync_timestamp>',
                 endpoint="api.ftrecord")
with app.test_request_context():
    base_url = flask.url_for('api.ftrecord')
```

I met the same error.
By using 'with app.test_request_context():', it works.